# Campagnolo Athena - Lost plastic part on front derailleur. Now the chain is droping on upshifting

Tags: repair, derailleur, replacement, campagnolo

Somehow the plastic part on the side/front of the derailleur is lost. Now I can't shift properly because the chain drops to the outside on an up shift.

The plastic part is visible in this image. Its the black thing.

[image]

Is there a spare part available or is this a warranty case?

Comment: Are you sure it's that missing bit of plastic that throws your chain off? It's on the outside of the derailleur and shouldn't even touch the chain. Check the min/max screws. (those small ones behind the mount)

Comment: The plastic part goes also in the other direction and prevents that the chain goes to far. I tried to fix this with the min max screw but the chain will not got on the bigger chainring after a chance.

Answer (score 1):

The spare part code is 5-FD-RE116 for double or FD-AT016 for triple and it's available from several online shops. LBSes specializing in road bikes should have it too.

Check out the spare parts catalogue from Campagnolo: http://www.campagnolo.com/media/files/035_250_Catalogue_spare%20parts_tools_Campagnolo_2015_part_A.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this missing plastic piece is the culprit. It does need to be there.

If the derailleur is within 3 years of purchase, is in use with a full Campagnolo drive train (chain, cassette, crankset and chainrings, no 3rd party joining link in the chain) and you have a valid proof of purchase, then it is possibly a valid warranty claim - the warranty can be operated by any bicycle shop, who will need to forward the part to a Service Centre where the problem will be assessed and if appropraite, the warranty operated.

As the main Campagnolo factory-appointed Warranty and Service Centre for the UK, we can assure you that the above answer is correct.

Comment: Graeme's [profile](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/13182/graeme) discloses that he is *Owner and head technician at Velotech Cycling Ltd*

Comment: Um, yes, Andy - that's why I included the para at the end "As the main Campag ... answer is correct" ... seemed reasonable to say that, so that the OP could see that what we say is accurate, if they didn't check my profile ...

Comment: My comment was more of a heads up for others :-) I can delete if you'd prefer.

Comment: Ach, no worries Andy! Nice to make your acquaintance BTW, even if it is only via t'interweb .... :-)

Comment: Graeme Can you give me a reference for this warranty statement?

Comment: Hi Penta, not 100% sure by what you mean by a reference, but if you just mention to your retailer that you have been in touch with Velotech Cycling Ltd as the main UK and Ireland Service and Warranty Centre for Campagnolo - and that this is our advice - they can always contact us if they are in any doubt. Our contacts are all at the Campagnolo website if they want to verify ... Cheers, Graeme